# EmguCV HasCuda Not working

Tags: emgucv

I'm trying to improve a real time detection using haarcascade, I've digged into the haarcascade's file to see that the HasCuda is not working, or the gpucascadeclassifier is not working, making the application unresponsive, I'm using a Nvidia 980 GTX (so it's not a hardware problem)

Sample Code:

```
if (GpuInvoke.HasCuda)
        {
           using (var car = new GpuCascadeClassifier(carFileName))
            {
                using (var gpuImage = new GpuImage<Bgr, byte>(image))
                using (var gpuGray = gpuImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>())
               {
                    var carRegion = car.DetectMultiScale(gpuGray, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty);
                    cars.AddRange(carRegion);
                }
            }
        }
```